# saving output as variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, scripting

I am working on a batch script and am trying to save part of the output of a command as a variable. My current script requires the user to enter a site code (e.g. 853), and it takes that code and uses it to query a sql database. The command I'm using is as follows:

`sqlcmd -S"localhost\SQLONESOURCE" -Uusername -Pmypassword -dOneSource -Q"select AdmSiteID from [10.33.144.114].onesource.dbo.admsites where siteid='%sitecode%'"`

When this command runs, I get the following output:

`AdmSiteID
------------------------------------

   AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE


(1 rows affected)`

I just want to take the AdmSiteID (AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE) and save that as a variable. It will always be in that format with the same number of characters and dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This batch code get the third line from your sqlcmd output:

```
for /F "skip=2" %%a in ('sqlcmd -S"localhost\SQLONESOURCE" -Uusername -Pmypassword -dOneSource -Q"select AdmSiteID from [10.33.144.114].onesource.dbo.admsites where siteid='%sitecode%'"') do (
   set thirdLine=%%a
   goto continue
)
:continue
echo %thirdLine%
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I don't know why i didn't see the "skip" argument in any of the documentation I was found for the for command.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to ensure your SQLCMD output includes some sort of unique text that you can search for.  For example, you could modify your query as follows:

```
"select 'FOO~' + AdmSiteID + '~' from [10.33.144.114].onesource.dbo.admsites where siteid='%sitecode%'"
```

Then write your SQLCMD output to a file by adding **-o %OUTPUT_FILE%** to your SQLCMD.EXE line, where **%OUTPUT_FILE%** has already been defined.

Then use a combination of **for** and **findstr.exe** to pull your file apart:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=~" %%D in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /l /c:"FOO~" %OUTPUT_FILE%') do set YOUR_VARIABLE=%%D
```

This hasn't been tested, but I know the theory is sound.  If it doesn't work, and you're struggling to fix it, let me know, and I'll spend more time on it.